# List view not showing my Results when retrieving data from azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

Here is my code

```
  public  List<string> Mycollection { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string storageConnectionString = "mystring";           
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("tablename");
        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
        foreach (CustomerEntity CustomerEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            Mycollection.Add(CustomerEntity.NAME);
        }
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Mynewpage());
    }
```

and here is my Mynewpage Xaml code

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:Page1/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>  
        <StackLayout> 
          <Label Text="koool"></Label>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mycollection }">                
        </ListView>
    <Label Text="koool"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

and here is an image of the output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4JNU.jpg)
every thing seems fine ,but I guess the problem lies in the way I am using binding

Comment: how is `Mynewpage` getting this data?  You aren't passing `Mycollection` to the page.

Comment: how can i pass it to the page ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the data to your page.  This doesn't happen automatically

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Mynewpage(Mycollection));
```

then in `Mynewpage`

```
public List<string> Mycollection { get; set; }

public Mynewpage(List<string> data)
{
  ...

  Mycollection = data;

  this.BindingContext = this;
  ...
}
```

and get rid of this

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:Page1/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Comment: sry again i would be grateful if u can provide the xaml syntax for the binding for the item source

Comment: u mean like this  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mycollection ></ListView>

Comment: alrdy used it but still nathing appear , when i remove Mycollection and try to see it from the intliisence it doesnt show up :(  sry for being such a pain i am a newbie

Comment: I forgot to add public to the property, see my edit