# Syncing local xamarin SQLite Database with Azure table storage Back-End

Tags: azure, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Here is my code used
`TODOITEM1.cs`

```
 public class TODOITEM1
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TEXT")]
    public string TEXT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "COMPLETE")]
    public bool COMPLETE { get; set; }
}
```

and here is `MainPage.Xaml.cs`

```
 string DbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MTZDATABASE3.db");
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("MTZDATABASE3.db");

        store.DefineTable<TODOITEM1>();           
        string URL6 = "https://mtzstorageaccount2.table.core.windows.net/TODOITEM1";           

        MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(URL6);

        await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        IMobileServiceSyncTable<TODOITEM1> todoTable = client.GetSyncTable<TODOITEM1>();                
      
        await todoTable.PullAsync("allTODOITEM", todoTable.CreateQuery());
```

and this is the error that appears `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: 'The request could not be completed.  (The specified resource does not exist.)`

and here is a screenshot of my table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xetVB.jpg)

Comment: "https://mtzstorageaccount2.table.core.windows.net/TODOITEM1" does not exist - that seems pretty obvious

Comment: well the image i provided states that it does exist , Could i possibly wrote the URI wrong or could it be an issue with the access Configuration for this table !

Comment: That seems very possible.

Comment: u have any idea how can i make a `MobileServiceClient` from a `StorageAccount` made from `ConnectionString` of my storageaccount  like the code in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328939/list-view-not-showing-my-results-when-retrieving-data-from-azure]